# How to start the first view every time when app resumes?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2

I am using `xcode4.2` and inside `appDidFinishLaunching` i am initializing `navigationController` with my first view and sets the `rootViewController` of app to `navigationController`.I want to show the first view every time when app resumes. How i can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is not using backgrounding. If you set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in Info.plist, when the user press the home button, your app will quit and next time it is launched it will start over and not resumed from where it was.

Otherwise, you can define `– applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `– applicationDidBecomeActive:` to go back to your first view whenever the app is resumed. Have a look at the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) reference and [Multitasking states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

Comment: but i am using the app in background because i set the UIBackgroundMode(location) or in xcode4.2 Required background modes(App registers for location updates) for notify the app for location updates.

Comment: You can pop to your root view controller in - applicationWillEnterForeground or -applicationWillEnterBackground.

Comment: @iosuser: if you need backgrounding, then you can use `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `applicationDidBecomeActive` as I suggested to display your first view; the way you do that depends on how your app manages its view...

Comment: @Pierre by using the popToRootViewController its done but by using this viewDidLoad is not getting called but i want to call the viewDidLoad also.

Comment: @iosuser, you should use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillLoad` for executing some code when the root controller is popped...

Comment: Thanks sergio and @Pierre i added popToRootViewController in applicationWillEnterForeground and used viewWillAppear for executing code now my problem is solved.